# Using a Chrome extension, open a page, perform an action, open another page, do same (repeat until all pages done)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension that iterates through a list of web pages (the URLs of these pages can be hard coded into some JavaScript array in a .js), perform the following actions...

- Take a screenshot
- Take the resulting screenshot and either store it locally or send it (the image data) to an API
- Move on to the next URL, rinse and repeat

I would like to do this without opening a new tab for each URL.

I tried all manner of things using a script that executes when the extension is called up. It appears that window.open("some URL", "_self") does not work. Using chrome.tab.create, as expected, opens a new tab each time. I was fine with this (for now), but then in the callback function, attempting to call chrome.tab.create again did not work. I then read about background scripts (service workers) and still no luck there. I was hoping in the callback function (newTab) => {...}, I could do something like this newTab.open("https://blah", some_callback) and cause the tab to be updated with the new URL and another callback (perhaps using chrome.tabs.update).

I am using manifest version 3

Thanks,

Matthew

Update: Looks like am lacking some contextual information. Seems that background JS (service workers) appear to be Node.js and, naturally, browser based JS is not. This means they would have two completely different namespaces, so would be curious as to how browser JS interacts with service worker JS (like any other server I assume)

Comment: @norio-yamamoto thanks, I certainly will

Comment: Hi @lastfreedom and welcome to stackoverflow, thanks for asking your question. I imagine it would be very hard to do that with a Chrome extension. This is possible using many many tools. I just read your update and it's exactly what I was getting to :) Good luck in your journey though

Comment: If you really want a chrome extension, you can use chrome.tabs.update to change the URL of the same tab. Once you really understand the architecture, it should be easy. Note that service worker has no relation to node.js, it's just a separate JS environment, but without `window` or DOM.

Comment: If you can detect when the screenshot procedure is finished, you can then iterate to the next value in the array and change the URL of the same tab you're in using `window.location.href = url_arr[i]` - just like @wOxxOm mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. First here's the manifest (version 3)...

```
{
    "name": "Screenshots from List",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Take screenshots based on a list of URLs",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "desktopCapture",
        "downloads",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Take Screenshots"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The content_script.js file is empty, but appears to be needed so the extensions menu contains a clickable entry (given my current, and no doubt limited, understanding of Chrome extensions)

The background.js script pauses after the URL for the tab is set, since in my use case, JavaScript continues to render the tab after the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event has fired...

```
var m_Clicked = false;
var m_Index = 0;
var m_UrlList = ["URL1", "URL2"];

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log("Clicked");
    m_Clicked = true;
    chrome.tabs.update({"url": m_UrlList[m_Index]});

});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    console.log("Clicked : " + m_Clicked);
    console.log(changeInfo.status);

    if (m_Clicked) {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {
                format: "png",
                quality: 100
            }, function (data) {

                chrome.downloads.download({
                        url: data,
                        filename: "pic_" + m_Index + ".png"
                    },
                    () => {
                        if (m_Index < m_UrlList.length) {
                            m_Index++;
                            chrome.tabs.update({"url": m_UrlList[m_Index]});
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    }
});
```